# Generate google map error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have the following script which supposed to generate a basic google map:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var weatherAPP = {

        generateMap: function(){

            console.log('called');

            var mapHolder = document.getElementById('#map');
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, 0.1275),
                zoom:10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapHolder, mapOptions);

        }

    };

    weatherAPP.generateMap();

});
```

`console.log('called')` gets called fine.

I have included the following scripts in order:

- google maps api
- jquery
- script

However I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

Comment: `getElementById('#map')`. Is your element actually `id="#map"?`

Comment: yes <section id="map"></section>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your element is: `<section id="map"></section>`

```
var mapHolder = document.getElementById('#map');
```

should be

```
var mapHolder = document.getElementById('map');
```

You must have confused it with jQuery or CSS in where you declare ids with the prefix `#`.

In `document.getElementById` you have to put the elements ID as it is with no prefix at all

Answer (score 1):

I is happening because you have # in getElementById('#map');

If you remove the # it will work :)

http://jsfiddle.net/zbyqoaju/1/

```
var weatherAPP = {

        generateMap: function () {

            console.log('called');

            var mapHolder = document.getElementById('map');
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, 0.1275),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapHolder, mapOptions);

        }

    };

    weatherAPP.generateMap();
```